# Blender 3.0.1 exports wrong Metallic/Roughness Map when exporting glTF2.0

Tags: export

I am new to Blender and am recently learning how to use it. I add a plane to the scene and applied base color to the Principled BSDF Node from an ImageTexture node. I also generated the grayscale of the texture using Paint.NET and applied the grayscale to roughness and metallic properties after some transforms. It looked nice inside Blender, but after I exported it to the glTF 2.0 file, it messes up, and the model seems to have a wrong roughness map applied to it. I also exported a .gltf file and textures separately, only to find that the G and B channel of the output roughness/metallic texture has completely the same values, which goes against the glTF2.0 specification. The spec states that metallic value should be stored in the B channel and roughness value should be stored in the G channel, and it seems that the roughness channel is overwritten by metallic values. Is this a problem in the Blender glTF export module or I have done something wrong?

This is how I configured my shading nodes:
[image: Node Configuration]
And this is the texture output of the glTF files(I compressed it as the original image exceeds the 2Mb limit)
[image: Metallic/Roughness Texture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally exporters can handle only certain fixed node graphs. The only node setups the glTF exporter recognizes for metallic/roughness (besides a constant) are:

[image: Texture -> Separate RGB -> Metallic]

A texture connected to Metallic/Roughness socket through a Separate RGB node. You can use whichever of the R, G or B channels you like. If your texture is grayscale you can skip the Separate RGB node and connect the Color straight to the metallic.

[image: Texture -> Separate RGB -> Multiply -> Metallic]

Same as above but with a Math node set to Multiply before the socket. This is exported as a glTF `metallicFactor`.

All other nodes are ignored.

---

So in your case, you can fix the metallic path by replacing the Map Range node with a Multiply by 0.3 node that does the same thing. But the Invert and Map Range on the roughness path cannot be exported; you'll have to prepare a separate roughness texture to use.