# Exporting texture with FBX doesn't work

Tags: export, .fbx

Exporting a single plane (floor in this case) as .fbx just with a changed color in Principled BSDF works. However, for my ring which has an image texture for color, metallic and roughness exporting as .fbx shows just model without texture. I put Path Mode to Copy and check Embed Textures.
Does it need to be baked or something to be properly exported and shown?
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252882/blender-3-0-1-exports-wrong-metallic-roughness-map-when-exporting-gltf2-0?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, it's for gltf version. Is it same for fbx or?

Comment: See @Jakemoyo's answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the Blender Documentation about the FBX Exporter:
[image]

**EDIT** However, it seems it is possible to export with materials packed into the FBX Exporter. Make sure that there aren't any excess nodes connected to your principled shader (Color Ramp, etc.) From my tests it seems like it will only accept textures connected directly into their corresponding Principled shader input. It won't work with AO mixed with the base color, it won't work with height plugged into the displacement input.

Basically your material has to look like this:
[image]

Then in the FBX Exporter change this setting to *Copy*.

[image]

This will create a .fbm folder that will bundle the textures along with it.

After that it seems to work.

Result in UE4.

[image]

I think if I had then file naming correct it would have auto-generated the material but anyways.

Comment: So basically you can't export material textures, only procedural?

Comment: No you can't export materials. Procedural textures are still textures, they are just generated on the fly with math, rather read in directly as an image.

Comment: What is then way around? What can I do? I have been always exporting for game engines so I export model + textures with it. But now I want it for product marketing so it can be seen in 3D viewer with textures on it

Comment: @Radoon I edited my response, figured it out.

Comment: Yeah, it probably only accept textures connected to principled BSDF. Thank for assistance!

Comment: No worries! I actually learned something myself! Thats what it's all about!